# D3 SVG added to leaflet is cut off when pan and zoomed

Tags: leaflet

I'm adding a D3 SVG containing nodes with lat and lng data and links to a leaflet map via:

```
var mapLayer = d3
    .select(backgroundMap.getPanes().overlayPane)
    .append('svg')
```

Everything is working great until I pan and zoom. The elements with the SVG are positioned correctly, but they are cut off due to the SVG dimensions.

[image]

I'm pretty new to Leaflet and I think I'm missing something fundamental - how can I ensure the entire SVG can always be seen?

Answer (score 0):

This is sorted now.

The majority of the solution can be found here:

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

However I was not using a GeoJSON file. An example of how this can be done can be found within the jsfiddle posted here:

[SVG circles don't get repositioned when zooming leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345987/svg-circles-dont-get-repositioned-when-zooming-leaflet-map?rq=1)

I had to add extra padding to avoid nodes being clipped - see [sync d3.js map and leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321145/sync-d3-js-map-and-leaflet-map?rq=1)

The viewbox values I was setting for the svg also had to be removed.